# Handling nil: Trying to avoid #try

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, error-handling, null

Yesterday, I introduced a bug into our codebase by calling `#titleize` on a string that could possibly come in as `nil`:

```
def route
  medication.route_name.titleize
end
```

This threw an error on production and a coworker fixed this by adding `try`:

```
def route
  medication.route_name.try(:titleize)
end
```

I'm not totally happy with this solution, after being really influenced by [Avdi's article on `#try`](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/06/28/do-or-do-not-there-is-no-try/), and I've been trying to come up with something I like better. Here are two possibilities.

Firstly, in Avdi's talk ["Confident Code"](http://cloud.nickcox.me/QIgl), he talks about asking for the data type you need: if you need a string, ask for a string. So I thought about this:

```
def route
  medication.route_name.to_s.titleize
end
```

This way, `nil` will be converted to empty string, and `#titleize` will be called, which will not error. The obvious issue with this is that you're calling `#to_s` on something which is only ever an instance of `String` or `NilClass`.

The only other approach I could think of was this:

```
def route
  medication.route_name.present? medication.route_name.titleize : ''
end
```

The issue here is the `if/else` parading around as prettier code through the use of a ternary operator, and the repetition of `medication.route_name`. This could be minified by delegating `route_name` to `medication`, or some other work around. But there's still the `if/else` conditional. And that's more code.

The bigger question here is how to handle `nil` values. This method is a pretty typical example of how this comes up. How would you handle it?

Comment: Smiley for you :-D just for 'Trying to avoid #try'

Answer (score 10):

> I introduced a bug into our codebase by calling #titleize on a string that could possibly come in as nil

When a problem is so pervasive, it's usually a sign that there is a conceptual problem with the language itself, some call it [void safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_safety), also dubbed "the billion-dollar mistake". Some languages, specially the functional ones, use an [Option type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type). Let's see the options in Ruby:

- `medication.route_name.try(:titleize)`. This is probably the most idiomatic approach in Rails. You say you're not totally happy, yes, it's ugly that a method name ended up being a symbol. Note, however, that if you want an empty string as fallback, you should write `medication.route_name.try(:titleize) || ""`.
- Very similar to `try`, I prefer the proxy approach of [andand](https://github.com/raganwald/andand)/[maybe](http://ick.rubyforge.org/): `medication.route_name.maybe.titleize || ""`.
- `medication.route_name.to_s.titleize`. IMO, that's dubious. You are calling `to_s` to a `nil` object. Yes, it happens to return `""`, but it could as well return `"nil"` (see for example Python: `str(None) #=> 'None'`). Too implicit.
- `medication.route_name.present? medication.route_name.titleize : ''`. You are protecting yourself against `nil` objects, not empty strings, so there is no need to use `present?`: `medication.route_name ? medication.route_name.titleize : ''`. As you say, this is simple but verbose. Also, imagine you have a chain of  nullable values, it becomes a real mess. That's why `andand` and similar libraries were created.

By the way, I've wrote about this subject at [RubyIdioms](https://github.com/tokland/tokland/wiki/RubyIdioms#user-content-managing-nils-the-maybe-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Another solid option is to use the [Safe Navigation Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator#Ruby) **&.** like this:

```
def route
  medication.route_name&.titleize
end
```

Comment: Your linked reference says, that this is available with Ruby 2.3 which was released at the end of 2015, two years after the original question. I would invite you to add a note on this in your answer.